# Arch Linux Laravel not found

Tags: linux, laravel, composer-php

I installed Laravel via composer

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

But when i try to create laravel app

```
laravel new app
```

I get error message

```
bash: laravel: command not found
```

I tried to set $PATH in bash_profile, but it is not working.

Composer location: `composer: /usr/bin/composer`

Comment: after setting $PATH, did you source .bash_profile or logout and login again?

Comment: Reloading terminals after `$PATH` changes super important here. Also the path is likely not the executable `/usr/bin/composer` but most likely `~/.composer/vendor/{{something}}`

Comment: yes, maybe path was wrong?What should i type?

Comment: this is what i added in ~/.bash_profile : export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH

Comment: Are you sure that's where it's at?

Comment: I see now that ~/.composer do not exist. But there is composer in /usr/bin, and if i run ./composer in that dir, i get list of commands for composer. Also i have already $PATH in bashrc, it is used for android-sdk, could that be a problem too?

Answer (score 0):

So when i deleted composer path from bashrc, i created project with 
    composer create-project laravel/laravel {directory} 4.2 --prefer-dist
and then i needed to install mcrypt and enable it in php.ini with

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

Now everything works.